# Merging tables in R with 2 common columns in R

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 tables which need to be merged, based on 2 common columns. Table A:

| Year | Month | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 1 | 10 |
| 2011 | 2 | 20 |
| 2012 | 1 | 30 |

Table B:

| Year | Month | Pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 1 | 100 |
| 2011 | 2 | 200 |
| 2012 | 1 | 300 |

I want a final table which includes all the 4 columns i.e. Year, Month, Temp and Pressure.

Comment: Are you familiar with the merge function?

Comment: for some reason the table is not visible. Yes I know about merge function, but I am having trouble merging based on 2 common columns.